# For Loop inside Template Literals?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, template-literals

Is it a way to loop inside Template Literals? Obviously this could be done by mapping an array like this:

```
array = ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(`foo ${array.map(i => i).join(" ")} bar`)
///foo a b c bar
```

But what if we need to loop somthing for specific times? like this:

```
`foo ${for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {Somthing}} bar`
```

Comment: Template literals allow embedded *expressions*, not *statements*. Consider instead sharing the problem you're trying to solve, as currently this seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: what is `Something`? you can convert any loop to s/t like an array or an generator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use an IIFE there:

```
`foo ${(function fun() {
  // Do your loop here
  // Return the result as a string
})()} bar`
```

I would advise against it and just create the normal function, call it, assign the return value to a variable and use the variable inside template literal placeholder.

Comment: Thanks, that dos the job:
`foo ${(function fun() {
    string =""
    for(let i = 0; i <10 ; i++){
    d+= i
    }
    return string
})()} bar`
//"foo 0123456789 bar"

however, this seems a little bit strange and I should stick to your advice.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you would advise against it?

Comment: @robfuscator Maybe for readability purposes. I myself don't see anything else in that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use reducer to achieve in ES6

```js
const anArray = [
  {
    "name": "pulha",
    "as": "puli"
  },
  {
    "name": "puli",
    "as": "moka"
  },
    {
    "name": "moka",
    "as": "starbucks"
  },
  {
    "name": "starbucks",
    "as": "sweet"
  },
    {
    "name": "sweet",
    "as": "krispey"
  },
  {
    "name": "krispey",
    "as": "free"
  }
];

$('#an-example-showing-template').append(`
  ${anArray.reduce((updated, latest) => updated.concat(`<li>${latest.name} alias ${latest.as}</li>`), '')}
`)
```

```css
#an-example-showing-template > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="an-example-showing-template"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks ~ This solution is working for my code.  It's worth using it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to implement your function outside the backtick expression like this:

```
function helloworld() {

let string;

for(let i = 0; i <10 ; i++){
string = 'Hello World!'    
} 
   return string
}

//Inside the backtick

`${helloworld()}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const tplFor=(statement,body)=>[...(function*(){}).constructor(`for(${statement})yield\`${body}\``)()].join("");
```

and then in your template do ${tplFor("const person of people","hello! ${person.firstName}")}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular/typescript, you can do it inside back ``:

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead style="color: darkred; font-weight: bolder; font-size:22px">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="font-weight: bolder; font-size:16px">
          ${
        (function myfunction() {
          let test: string[] = []
          for (let item of YourList) {
            
            test.push(
           `<tr>
            <td>${item.name}</td>
            <td>${item.age}</td>
            </tr>`
            )
          }
          return test
        })()
        }

    </tbody>
  </table>
```